# How to get string from whole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a string whose text is something like:

> Ebook/AspNetBook.Pdf/.NetBook

or

> Ebook/Asp.Net/AspNetBook.Pdf/.NetBook

or may be this

> Ebook/Asp.Net/.NetBook/AspNetBook.Pdf

That means string may be come with many forward slashes and it will not come in fix format. I want to get file name and its ext `AspNetBook.Pdf` from this string.

I have tried to get string to using sub string or replace character before period but do not get proper result.

Comment: Can u show the code you have tried ??

Comment: In your text there will be only two forward slashes ?

Answer (score 1):

If your strings always have that particular form `string1/string2/string3` you can either use a simple string split or a regular expression.

```
var xx = input.Split('/')[1];
```

Or

```
var xx = Regex.Match(input, @".+/(.+)/.+").Groups[1].Value;
```

Be aware, this contains no error checking, for instance if the input does not match the given form

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
        string st = "Ebook/AspNetBook.Pdf/.NetBook";
        string newst = st.Substring(st.IndexOf('/') + 1);
        string outptst = newst.Substring(0,newst.IndexOf('/'));
```

since you wanted to get the string between 2 forward slashes. This would give you the correct output required.

[image: The output is the desired string]

Comment: You're assuming that the string is exactly as described above with no additional or missing slashes.  You still have an open question to the OP that hasn't been clarified.  I'd consider this premature and fragile.  I do agree that it is correct **if the OP's described string is verbatim and will never change**.

Comment: @DavidL: I have attached the image to prove.

Comment: This answers what OP is looking for, if not an upvote but I believe it doesn't require to have a downvote too.

Comment: Without clarification I don't believe the question answerable, but I do agree that since it does appear to solve an unclear question, your answer doesn't deserve a downvote and I retracted mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
string st = "Ebook/AspNetBook.Pdf/.NetBook";
string out = st.Split('/')[1];
```

Be aware that this will only work if you always have a `/` in your input and if it is always the second value.

Comment: This looks more convincing. :)

Comment: Maybe I should not have used the out keyword as a variable name but...

Answer (score -1):

Here p1 will find first index of '/' and p2 will index of '/' right after p1.

```
String text= "Ebook/AspNetBook.Pdf/.NetBook";
int p1=text.indexOf('/');   
int p2=-1;
if(p1!=-1)
p2=text.indexOf('/',p1+1);

if(p1!=-1&&p2!=-1)
System.out.print(text.substring(p1+1,p2);
```

Comment: This is really just a more convoluted and confusing version of Mohit's answer.

Comment: The second parameter of your `substring` call is wrong. According to documentation, it should contain the length of the substring and not the end index, as it does in your code